# Correct use of comma?

Tags: orthography, commas, present-participles

Should there be a comma after 1975?

> Peter Singer wrote Animal Liberation in 1975, igniting the modern animal movement.

Comment: I'd write it as "in 1975 and ignited" or "In 1975, Peter Singer wrote Animal Liberation, which ignited..." or "Peter Singer wrote Animal Liberation in 1975, which ignited...". I find that gerund-phrase-tack-on too often ambiguous.

Comment: It works here, but the comma needs to be included. Moving it to after _Liberation_ changes the meaning. I agree that the -ing-participial-clause-tack-on is often ambiguous, but would say that _igniting_ here is more verbal than nounal, and most authorities disallow the term 'gerund' for this usage (some disallow it altogether). Authorities are divided over whether to call -ing - whatsits phrases or (non-finite) clauses.

Answer (score 1):

In “Peter Singer wrote Animal Liberation in 1975, igniting the modern animal movement”, the part after “1975,” is a non-essential dependent clause, so a  comma is appropriate to separate it from the independent clause before it.  See  wikipedia's [subordinate clause](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subordinate_clause#English_punctuation) article.

Answer (score 1):

Unquestionably. "Igniting" is the beginning of a dependent clause (a clause that adds information to an independent clause). It can't stand alone as a sentence, and it adds information to the independent clause ("Peter Singer wrote Animal Liberation in 1975"), but it is not necessary to the meaning of the independent clause. This makes it a non-essential clause, and it therefore must be set off by a comma.

You might think of it this way: It's a separate *thought* from the main one, so separate it with a comma. If it was a necessary and integral continuation of the main *thought*, you wouldn't separate it this way (but you would need a subordinating conjunction - and that's another discussion).